# Printing 11 numbers per line?

Tags: java, for-loop

I have to make a variation of the famous "FizzBuzz" code where it counts up to a number that the user inputs and only prints 11 numbers per line. My code seems to be somewhat working, but it repeats the same thing 11 times each line.

Can someone please help me fix this?

```
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

public class CozaLoza2 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        String n = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Please input an interger");
        int result = Integer.parseInt(n);
        for (int i = 0; i <= result; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j <= 10; j++) {

                System.out.print(" ");

                if (i % 3 == 0 && i % 5 == 0 && i % 7 == 0) {
                    System.out.print("CozaLozaWoza");
                }

                if (i % 3 == 0 && i % 5 == 0) {
                    System.out.print("CozaLoza");

                } else if (i % 5 == 0) {
                    System.out.print("Loza");

                } else if (i % 3 == 0) {
                    System.out.print("Coza");

                } else if (i % 7 == 0) {
                    System.out.print("Woza");

                } else {
                    System.out.print(" " + i);
                }
            }
        }
        System.out.println();
    }
}
```

Here is the output I get if I enter the number "20" into that program

> CozaLozaWozaCozaLoza CozaLozaWozaCozaLoza CozaLozaWozaCozaLoza CozaLozaWozaCozaLoza CozaLozaWozaCozaLoza CozaLozaWozaCozaLoza CozaLozaWozaCozaLoza CozaLozaWozaCozaLoza CozaLozaWozaCozaLoza CozaLozaWozaCozaLoza CozaLozaWozaCozaLoza  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  2  2  2  2  2  2  2  2  2  2  2 Coza Coza Coza Coza Coza Coza Coza Coza Coza Coza Coza  4  4  4  4  4  4  4  4  4  4  4 Loza Loza Loza Loza Loza Loza Loza Loza Loza Loza Loza Coza Coza Coza Coza Coza Coza Coza Coza Coza Coza Coza Woza Woza Woza Woza Woza Woza Woza Woza Woza Woza Woza  8  8  8  8  8  8  8  8  8  8  8 Coza Coza Coza Coza Coza Coza Coza Coza Coza Coza Coza Loza Loza Loza Loza Loza Loza Loza Loza Loza Loza Loza  11  11  11  11  11  11  11  11  11  11  11 Coza Coza Coza Coza Coza Coza Coza Coza Coza Coza Coza  13  13  13  13  13  13  13  13  13  13  13 Woza Woza Woza Woza Woza Woza Woza Woza Woza Woza Woza CozaLoza CozaLoza CozaLoza CozaLoza CozaLoza CozaLoza CozaLoza CozaLoza CozaLoza CozaLoza CozaLoza  16  16  16  16  16  16  16  16  16  16  16  17  17  17  17  17  17  17  17  17  17  17 Coza Coza Coza Coza Coza Coza Coza Coza Coza Coza Coza  19  19  19  19  19  19  19  19  19  19  19 Loza Loza Loza Loza Loza Loza Loza Loza Loza Loza Loza

Comment: Its not clear what you expect. Please post input and expected output

Comment: Please indent your code properly, you can use your IDE to do it for you. It's hard to read the code otherwise.

Comment: Yes, it repeats the same thing 11 times, that's what the `for (int j ...` loop is doing. If you don't want this, the code in the loop should probably somehow depend on `j`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm happy to announce that your own lack of indentation was your downfall. This mess

```
  }
}
  }
     System.out.println();
}
}
```

should be this mess:

```
  }
}
     System.out.println();
  }
}
}
```

And now go learn how to indent and fix your indentation.

Also, in the outer loop `for (int i = 0; i <= result; i++)` you are running on `result + 1` values. Probably you need `i < result`.

(Just in case the question gets edited, I am talking about the original.)

Answer (score 0):

Your code produce exactly :

```
input (20 in your test) : for (int i=0; i<=result; i++)

x 11   :  for (int j=0; j<=10; j++)
```

And only one CRLF (at the end !)  => put it before

Answer (score 0):

Probably you have to move `System.out.println();` one bracket above. This code should be works fine

```
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

public class CozaLoza2 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        String n = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Please input an interger");
        int result = Integer.parseInt(n);
        for (int i = 0; i <= result; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j <= 10; j++) {

                System.out.print(" ");

                if (i % 3 == 0 && i % 5 == 0 && i % 7 == 0) {
                    System.out.print("CozaLozaWoza");
                }

                if (i % 3 == 0 && i % 5 == 0) {
                    System.out.print("CozaLoza");

                } else if (i % 5 == 0) {
                    System.out.print("Loza");

                } else if (i % 3 == 0) {
                    System.out.print("Coza");

                } else if (i % 7 == 0) {
                    System.out.print("Woza");

                } else {
                    System.out.print(" " + i);
                }
            }
            System.out.println();  // moved line
        }
    }
}
```